# Points with different radius using HeatMapWithTime in Folium

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I'm trying to plot a heatmap timelapse using Folium. However, I need each point to have a different radius.

I've tried the following:

```
from folium import plugins

map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[-23.5506507, -46.6333824],
                    zoom_start = 10) 

# Ensure you're handing it floats
df_acc['LAT'] = df_acc['LAT'].astype(float)
df_acc['LONG'] = df_acc['LONG'].astype(float)
df_acc['RADIUS'] = df_acc['RADIUS'].astype(int)




heat_df = df_acc
heat_df = heat_df[['LAT', 'LONG', 'RADIUS']]

# Create weight column, using date
heat_df['Weight'] = df_acc['TEMPO']
heat_df['Weight'] = heat_df['Weight'].astype(float)
heat_df = heat_df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['LAT','LONG', 'Weight'])

# List comprehension to make out list of lists
heat_data = [[[row['LAT'],row['LONG']] for index, row in heat_df[heat_df['Weight'] == i].iterrows()] for i in range(0,40)]
heat_radius = [[[row['RADIUS']] for index, row in heat_df[heat_df['Weight'] == i].iterrows()] for i in range(0,40)]
# Plot it on the map
hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(heat_data,radius=heat_radius,auto_play=True,max_opacity=0.8)
hm.add_to(map_hooray)
# Display the map
map_hooray
```

However, when I run this, it only plots the map without any points.
[image]

If I remove the *radius=heat_radius* parameter, the points are plotted correclty, however they all have the same radius.
[image]

Can this be done with HeatMapWithTime? Or will have to attempt a different approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So here's a similar case for a standard heatmap:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188739

The `radius` argument is expected to be an int, and is the same for all points in each HeatMap object. So the above answer's solution is to create a HeatMap object for each desired radius.

Since you want this radius based on your data, one approach would be

1. split your df based on radius
2. for each distinct radius, first create a heatmap object, specifying the radius as an int. Then add this heatmap

Something like

```
for radius, df in heat_df.groupby('RADIUS'):
    ... # generate data in format needed using df
    hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTimeFrame(heat_data, radius=radius, ...)
    hm.add_to(map_hooray)
```